# How to join elements in array based on their value

Tags: javascript

This is my array

```
["9", "8", "4", "×", "5", "4", "3"]
```

I want to join the elements before and after `"×"` so that I have

```
stringA = "984"
```

and

```
stringB = "543"
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd join by the empty string, then split by `×` and destructure:

```js
const arr = ["9", "8", "4", "×", "5", "4", "3"];
const [stringA, stringB] = arr.join('').split('×');
console.log(stringA, stringB);
```

Comment: Would you please explain what manner of black magic is being summoned here? How in the world does it spread the split into the 2 variables stringA and stringB. Please. For us mortals...

Comment: Splitting on a string will return an array of items. Destructuring syntax allows you to extract items from an iterable into standalone variable names. Eg `const [item0, item1] = arr` is equivalent to `const item0 = arr[0]; const item1 = arr[1]`

Comment: Brilliant! Code poetry. OP is getting an A+ for sure. lol

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = ["9", "8", "4", "×", "5", "4", "3"];

const getData = (array, separator) => {
  const index = array.findIndex(e => e === separator);

  if (index != -1) {
    let stringA = array.slice(0, index).join("");
    let stringB = "";
    if (index != array.length - 1) {
      stringB = array.slice(index + 1, array.length).join("");
    }
    console.log("stringA", stringA);
    console.log("stringB", stringB);
  } else {
    //do something
  }
}

getData(array, "×");
```